# SolR pagination ISSUE

Tags: solr, pagination

I am working on java web project based on solr search engine. 
I am looking for an alternative pagination way because solr has a known bug using start and rows attributes.
Do you know a solution (solr or java)?
Consider I have a lot of contents from query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the bug with using the start & rows ????

Comment: take a look:http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/lucene-solr-and-deep-paging